# Can a MBP 15'' early 2011 run DDR3L ram?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

I have an early-2011 MBP 15' with an Intel I7 2,2 GHZ core. I'm thinking in upping the RAM to 16GB with 2x8 DDR3L sticks.

I've read that using DDR3L with this core is not recommended, is this correct? Can I safely use these sticks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Please take a look at [this link from Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=MacBook%20Pro%20%2815-inch%2C%20Early%202011%29&pl=Apple&cat=RAM), which states that the MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) can run:

```
Memory Type: DDR3 PC3-10600, DDR3 (non-ECC)
Maximum Memory: 16GB
Slots: 2
```

The website even provides you with the recommended RAM for your computer. Look at the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I know I can go for 16GB, what I want to know is if the sticks can be DDR3L (notice the final L). Thanks for your time.

Comment: As stated on the Crucial website, 2011 Macbook Pro = 16GB DDR3 1333MHz RAM is the maximum and safe option - you can also use DDR3L (but not recommended). The newer models (2012 and 2013) can use DDR3L.

Comment: Can you share your source? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4026784?start=0&tstart=0](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4026784?start=0&tstart=0). This says that "DDR3L is required by the industry spec to work at 1.5V, so even if your computer was designed for DDR3 (any mac made before June, 2012), it would work with DDR3L too, but use more power assuming the 1600MHz parts work in 1333MHz machines (according to user testimonials at Newegg, they do work.)".

Comment: Thanks, from what I read on the post, the use of DRR3L IS actually recommended.

Comment: @mcabral, I know that it did say that, but it also says that the it would use more power. This would lower your battery life. In my opinion, a longer battery life is more important, but yes, it should work just fine.